# display the output from mat file

Tags: matlab, file

Please, any one help me: how can I display the output (image file name, mean color image, color histogarm) to see it, which I saved it in sruct of array in mat file

Comment: Yes it is matlab file if u have any coding to display this file

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can [load mat files](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Octave_Programming_Tutorial/Saving_and_loading_a_MAT-file) (MatLAB) formats in the free software GNU Octave.

Loading it would give you a new variable, let's say `a`

After you loaded it, you can display it according to the structure using octave commands.

GNU octave can be downloaded here: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html

Example `hist(a)`

Comment: Thank u for replying ...
please how can i get the software GNU Octave and put it in the work folder in order to use it?